# VB.NET JavaScriptSerializer() deserializing dictionary array members

Tags: vb.net, json

I am trying to deserialize a JSON string that looks like so:

```
    {'type':'clientlist','client_list':[]}
```

I am using JavaScriptSerializer() to do it. For some reason the JavaScriptSerializer() is choking on the member 'client_list'. It doesn't give very good info. The error it gives is:

```
    ArgumentException was unhandled:
    Invalid JSON primitive: .
```

So, as you can see its pretty non-descriptive. I have tried all sorts of different ways of deserializing it, even like so:

```
    Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = jss.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(json)
```

And it still gives that same error. Is it not possible to parse that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would define a model to represent my JSON data:

```
Public Class MyModel
    Public Property Type() As String
    Public Property Client_list() As String()
End Class
```

and then deserialize the JSON string to this model:

```
Dim json = "{'type':'clientlist','client_list':['client 1','client 2']}"
Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim model As MyModel = jss.Deserialize(Of MyModel)(json)
```

Comment: That works thanks. For some reason the json I am getting, it thinks that there is a '.' at the end that I cant see.

Comment: Yeah the "." at the end was because I was mishandling my recv buffer. THANKS A BUNCH! :)